# How to generate random numbers in C two colons?

Tags: c, random, numbers

I need in c code that generates two numbers in horizontally...so that i can get token numbers for my login system.

I need that i get this:

```
token=0.152644,0.429187
```

so in example i have token= and random generated numbers that have at beginning 0. and then 6 random generated numbers separated with , sign.
How to get get this in C?

I have try this code but it does not give me what i want_

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef
union
{
    char tmp[sizeof(unsigned long long)];
    unsigned long long myll;
} ll_t;


unsigned long long llrand(void)
{
    FILE *in=fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    ll_t ll_u;
    fread(ll_u.tmp, sizeof(ll_u.tmp), 1, in);
    fclose(in);
    return ll_u.myll;
}

int main()
{
    char tmp1[64]={0x0};
    char working[64]={0x0};
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i< 1; i++)
    {
        while(strlen(tmp1) < 6)
        {
            sprintf(working, "%lu", llrand() );
            strcat(tmp1, working);
        }
        tmp1[6]=0x0;

        printf("%s\n", tmp1);
        *tmp1=0x0;
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

From output i get this:

```
747563
102595
```

Can code be simple and short?

Comment: So you have 2 random 6 digit numbers? Why not just add a "0." to the front of each of them and print them with a comma between them...?

Comment: I know this but i need short code...because i im running on embeded device that is low on resources and this code runs very slow...cpu is 400mhz...so if you can please write shorter code..i try using time random numbers but it gives me each time same value

Comment: @John Why do you thing generating a random number between 0 and 1 is less complex and resource demanding than generating numbers say between 1 and 33000 or so.?  Also, the length of your code is not a valid measure of execution time..

Comment: Time&size-constraints, but using `printf`-family?

Comment: I posted answer above..i got it working...thanks for suggestions.

Comment: That is one slow CPU! "cpu is 400mhz".  Instead of **milli-Hertz**, did you mean 400Mhz?  ;-)

Comment: The `printf` format specifier should be `%llu` for an `unsigned long long int`, not `%lu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rand() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int randomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    /* generate secret number between min and max: */
    int res = rand() % (max-min+1) + min;
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        printf("%d ", randomNumber(10, 1000000));
    return 0;
}
```

That is full detail for rand():
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Thanks for replay i get output that i need...thanks for helping me and posting code. I accept this answer.

Comment: `randomNumber(10, 1000000)` will not return `1000000`.  It will return values [10, 999999] which in not between "between min and max"

Comment: Thanks you, chux. It would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that is working perfect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int n1, n2;
  time_t t;  

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    n1 = rand() % 1000000 + 1;
    n2 = rand() % 1000000 + 1;

    printf("token=0.%d,0.%d\n", n1, n2);

  return 0;
}
```

And output is:

```
token=0.289384,0.930887
```

Comment: This will not print out values like `token=0.000001,0.000002`.  Need to reconsider the format.

Answer (score 0):

A propose a different approach. Instead of generating 2 numbers and format them into the output string, generate 12 different digits and put them directly in place.

```
srand(time(0));
char output[] = "taken=0.XXXXXX,0.YYYYYY";
for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        output[9 * n + 8 + k] = rand() % 10 + '0';
        // you might want to write a function that deals with rand() bias
    }
}
puts(output);
```